# Passing data from wizard page to wizard in eclipse Swt

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a check box on my wizard page.On selection of a checkbox i need to send the selection value to wizard.

Please suggest me best approach to do the same.

Comment: You can have the pojo model for that checkbox and other widgets which can be updated when user press next button. When user will press finish then you can pass that model back to caller of the wizard

Comment: What do you mean by  'send the selection vaue to wizard'? Do you mean the class that implements `Wizard`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your wizard page you can call

```java
IWizard wizard = getWizard();
```

The `wizard` value you get will be your wizard class (say it is called `MyWizard`), so you call do:

```java
if (wizard instanceof MyWizard) {
   MyWizard myWizard = (MyWizard)wizard;

   myWizard.setXXXX(value);
}
```

where `setXXXX` is some method you write in the wizard to accept the selection value.